# Scrolling UITextView over UIimageView like facebook popup images

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uitextview

[image: How can i scroll a text view over an imageview something like in the facebook application]

I have an array of images and must be scrolled horizontally which i could manage, But in each image the description of the image but be scrolled upwards above the image something like i shown in the image. How it is possible?

Thanx
Jacu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a (horizontal) UIScrollView that contains UIView's. Each of the UIView's then contains an UIImageView, and another (vertical) UIScrollView that contains the UITextView's.

Make sure that:

- the contentSize.height of the horizontal UIScrollView is smaller than or equal to its height
- the contentSize.width of the vertical UIScrollView is smaller than or equal to its width
- the UIImageView is added before the UIScrollView to the containing UIView
- the background of the UITextView is (semi-)transparent

By the way, if the text is not editable, then you'll be better off using UILabel instead of UITextView